# How do I apply a clipping mask on certain objects in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I want to apply a clipping mask (a circle) that hides anything outside the circle from a certain set of objects but I want to leave the background visible

So basically something like this

[image]

Answer (score 4):

See the cartoon:

[image]

1) There are colored random objects on a grey-black background. The colored objects are grouped for easy selection and all background objects are another group.

2) Add the clipping mask on the top of all

3) Select the clipping mask and all objects you want to be clipped. Be sure not to select anything you want to keep out of the clipping process. The outsiders can be anywhere, even at the clipping area. They survive if they are not selected.

4) Goto Object > Clipping Mask > Make.

Comment: Thank you so much!!! I have another question, lets say i want to make the clipping mask to hide the lower part of a building but show the upper part of it outside the clipping mask

Comment: Should I duplicate the object and cut it into 2 parts one for the lower part and one for the upper part or is there a better way to do it?

Comment: @goldfrappp if you want to save something outside the clipping mask, do not select it. If that something is a part of an object that you are selected for clipping, it vanishes.  Your options 1) Have copies 2) clip separately with a different clipping mask. You should learn if the pathfinder panel can offer something useful. Please do not extend the question in comments, Ask a new question.